# Ubuntu Touch date picker HTML5

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, html5

I'm working on an app for ubuntu touch in html5 but Im wondering what components I should use for a date or time picker. I've asked it a couple of times on IRC but never got an answer

greetz
JustCarakas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the Ubuntu HTML5 UI toolkit (0.1.2) does not have a specific widget for date or time pickers.

So you need to create your own set of widgets, maybe using some text fields and an option selector.